# Default constructor coverage issue in jacoco

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, lombok, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am using jacoco in my spring boot project. My issues is that compiler generate default constructor and jacoco gives coverage issue for this default constructor, how can I exclude this default constructor from jacoco coverage, I don't want to use `@NoArgsConstructor` annotation because I have so many classes in which I'm facing this issue and I have to add this `@NoArgsConstructor` in all those classes one by one. Any better solution there?

I tried `@NoArgsConstructor` annotation and it solved my issue but I have too many classes so I have to add this in all classes that I don't want

Answer (score 1):

You should create the `lombok.config` file in your project root folder adding `lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true` inside it.

So, **JaCoCo** will ignore (by its design) al the methods annotated by **lombok** `@Generated` annotation.

Comment: I tried this but constructor generated by  compiler is not ignore by jacoco   because constructor is not annotated even using lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true